# What is the longest lasting hyperinflation period in history?

Tags: inflation

I guess hyperinflation periods depend on the definition of hyperinflation, which makes it hard to define and find comparative data. I could find which has been the worse in terms of percentages (Hungary), but what has been historically the longest lasting one in terms of time duration?

Comment: By some [accounts](https://www.cato.org/sites/cato.org/files/images/troubled-currencies-project/routledge-handbook-of-major-events-in-economic-history-world-hyperinflations.pdf) , Nicaraguan hyperinflation, which lasted for 58 months: from June of 1986 until March of 1991